# c++ function proxy for execution control

Tags: c++, templates, boost, bind, functor

I want to make a "function proxy" that:

1. It is a function object.
2. It's return type and argument type(s) are "inherited" automatically
   from a given "base" function type as template argument. the "base"
   function type could be one of (function pointer / boost::function / boost::bind)
3. It is initialized with a function object of the given type.
4. When it is called (as you can call the original function), it is able to
   store the call into something like boost::bind, and pass it to somewhere else
   (intentionally, a thread-safe queue, so that it can be invoked later, in another
    thread.), then return the call's result.

And for now, my problem is how (and is it even possible) to create this (functor) class
using template teq, and pass the unknown argument list to bind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename R, typename... ARGS>
class Proxy {
  typedef std::function<R(ARGS...)> Function;
  Function f;
 public:
  Proxy(Function _f) : f(_f) {}
  R operator(ARGS... args) {
    std::function<R> bound = std::bind(f, args...);
    send_to_worker_thread(bound);
    wait_for_worker_thread();
    return worker_thread_result();
  }
};

// Because we really want type deduction
template<typename R, typename... ARGS>
Proxy<R,ARGS...>* newProxy(R(*x)(ARGS...)) {
  return new Proxy(std::function<R,ARGS...>(x);
}
```

I haven't actually tested this.

You'll probably want something asynchronous, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks. And... is there any way I can do this in c++98 (I know it's a silly question, but...)?

Comment: Doing this without variadic templates would be very hard, unless you know something about what sort of parameters your functions will take.

Comment: I think you meant `typedef std::function<R(ARGS...)>` ?

Comment: @HalimQarroum: Indeed.  Edited.  This is what happens when I don't test things